# CakePHP 301 redirect getting url parameters with explode causes loop

Tags: cakephp, loops, http-status-code-301, explode, slug

SOLVED: see my comment

I've put my id and slug inside the same url parameter (folder) to shorten my urls.

Example: www.domain/gsm/1_samsung-galaxy-s-iii-16-gb where "1" is the id and "samsung-galaxy-s-iii-16-gb" is the slug.

This works great but now I'm trying to build a 301 redirect script that checks the slug in the url to the slug in the db and if they don't match up the user is 301 redirected to the right url.

But for some reason I end up in a redirect-loop because the script doesn't refresh the whole url but just adds the right slug after the wrong slug and of course keeps doing this untill the browser holds..

So www.domain/gsm/1_bladiebla redirect to www.domain/gsm/1_bladiebla_samsung-galaxy-s-iii-16-gb_samsung-galaxy-s-iii-16-gb_samsung-galaxy-s-iii-16-gb_samsung-galaxy-s-iii-16-gb.................

This is the view function from the controller:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $this->Smartphone->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Smartphone->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid smartphone'));
    }
    $this->set('smartphone', $this->Smartphone->read(null, $id));

    $pieces = explode('_', $this->params['pass'][0]);

    if ($pieces[1] != $this->Smartphone->field('slug')) {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $id.'_'.$this->Smartphone->field('slug')), 301);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I solved this myself. Turned out the problem lay in using the $id in the redirect url which is evil because $id works fine when keeping the id and slug devided by /.

Anyways this i the working line:

    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->Smartphone->field('id').'__'.$this->Smartphone->field('slug')));

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question...